time from gettimeofday() seems to be updated only once a second in kernel 5.xx versus 2.6
I read pcap packets in a loop and then try to timestamp those packets.
On a 2.6 kernel (e.g. centOs 6.8) it works correctly, but on 5.15 kernel (e.g. OEL 8) the time within 1 second hardly change 100µsec. Has this something to do with "NO_HZ: Reducing Scheduling-Clock Ticks" since there are more parameters in kernel 5.15 than in 2.6 the compiled program works correctly on my CentOs 6.8, but not on OEL 7 or 8.
Part of the code:
while ((prec = pcap_next_ex(cap, &header, &pkt_data)) >= 0) {
    // more code

    // Time in msec
    struct timeval tv;
    time_t sec_midnight = time(NULL) % 86400;
    if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL)) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
    }
    double usec = (double) tv.tv_usec;
    double frametime = (double) sec_midnight;
    frametime = frametime + usec / 1000000.0;

    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, &ts);
    printf("Frametime = %f %f %i\n", frametime, usec, ts.tv_nsec);
}

Output of the program:

Frametime = 31139.900089 900089.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900145 900145.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900200 900200.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900256 900256.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900311 900311.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900366 900366.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900422 900422.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900477 900477.000000 899621443
Frametime = 31139.900533 900533.000000 899621443
            ==> When the second changes, the usec changes with a big step.    
Frametime = 31140.543455 543455.000000 542621443
Frametime = 31140.543519 543519.000000 542621443
Frametime = 31140.543575 543575.000000 542621443
Frametime = 31140.543630 543630.000000 543621443
Frametime = 31140.543656 543656.000000 543621443
Frametime = 31140.543712 543712.000000 543621443
Frametime = 31140.543768 543768.000000 543621443
Frametime = 31140.543823 543823.000000 543621443
Frametime = 31140.543878 543878.000000 543621443


Instead of showing an extract from a larger program, you should create a [mcve] that everyone can run and experiment with.  You shouldn't need any of the pcap stuff to demonstrate this.

Also, please don't ignore the return value from clock_gettime() - if it's not doing what you want, you should check whether it's reporting problems.  Why are you using CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE for the final value?  It's no surprise that changes less often than the earlier values.

From an announcement when the _COARSE clocks were introduced: they "return the time at the last tick".  Switch to plain CLOCK_REALTIME and the coarseness should go away.

In my experience gettimeofday accesses the same clock as CLOCK_REALTIME.  If you're seeing unexpected coarseness in gettimeofday, that's odd.

@Wim69, Avoid format mismatch: "%f %f %i\n" --> "%f %f %li" as tv_nsec is a long.  Avoid relying on int and long as the same size.

gettimeofday() was marked obsolescent by POSIX years ago and I think it was removed completely from the newest version. Don't use it in new code.

You are using multiple syscalls to get the time. These could vary because of timeslicing. Use a single call to clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts); to get the time atomically. You can derive all the other values from this (e.g. time(NULL) becomes ts.tv_sec).

Side note: A 2.6.x kernel was obsolete some 20 years ago. I hope you're not still using it for anything real (and this is just an academic exercise).
